# Root/Naked domain and DDOS

Tags: attack-prevention, dns, denial-of-service, ddos, dns-domain

Some services like Github has DDOS mitigation measures for their root/naked domain, but not other subdomain(s).

What so special about the root domain concerning the DDOS attacks?

[1] http://instantclick.io/github-pages-and-apex-domains

Answer (score 2):

You usually set up a host name for DDOS protection by having a DNS CNAME record that points to the DDOS protection provider. This lets the provider adjust the IP address (or addresses) that the domain points to.

Setting up www.domain.com to use a CNAME record is easy. It's not so easy for domain.com because once a host name has a CNAME record, it cannot have any other records, and domain.com would usually have MX and NS records to handle mail and DNS resolution.

However, CloudFlare now supports [CNAME flattening](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root) which does allow this.